# Boost failing to install

Tags: libraries, installer, c++

I'm trying to install Boost libraries using the [auto-installer from here](http://www.boostpro.com/download/). I keep getting errors "Failed to unzip ???" where ??? are strange symbols. All I can do is click ok. How can I install this (and how can I quite the installer because the whole things locked up with all these errors)?

Comment: Perhaps try a different mirror. If you have a different machine you can test with, perhaps try installing there too just to see if it's an issue with the machine you're using now. I use the BoostPro installers semi-regularly and don't run into any problems.

Comment: When I got through all the error messages it had said the installation completed successfully but it actually didn't. No new files were created except the uninstaller.

Comment: It looks like BoostPro has been discontinued. Why don't you try the official version from boost.org?

Comment: Just so you know I (the op) didn't set the bounty and have long since moved on to different projects.

Answer (score 1):

"Failed to unzip" usually means that the zip file is corrupt, which is usually due to interrupt in the download process, try to extract the file manually to see if it opens, if it is corrupt, re-download it.

I recommend going to boost.org and download the latest version from there, and it should install fine.

Comment: I realize now that my proxy was locking the download of the zip files... That why it was so quick to download